# Is there a way to create a clipping mask of a layer that is not immediately below it

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

I want to make the 'hair shadow layer' a clipping mask of the 'hair layer'(without unclipping the hair layer). Is it possible to do it? If so, how?

Comment: yes it is possible just wait till i prepare answer :) Daniellilo already posted answer :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Wouldn't it be better to have the hair shadow layer under the hair layer?

Comment: If I put the hair shadow under the hair layer, it would not be visible. My intention was to paint the shadow over the hair but to avoid accidentally painting over other places where there was no hair.

Answer (score 3):

Add a **Layer Mask** to the *Shadow Layer*

- Holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win, click the *Hair Layer* thumbnail to load the transparency selection
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Win to invert the selection
- Click the *Shadow Layer*
- Click the **Add Layer Mask** icon

[image]